# SPServices Sum returned values

Tags: javascript, spservices, splistitem

I'm using SPServices to query a SharePoint 2010 list, a can get the values that I want but when I try to sum all of then I get this"

[image]

Here is the code that i use:

```
var TotalAmount = 0.00;

$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
listName: {list guid},
viewName: {view guid},
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='AP' /><FieldRef Name='Amount' /></ViewFields>",
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='AP' /><Value Type='Text'>"+areaValue+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status){
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
            var liHtml=$(this).attr("ows_Title");
            var app =$(this).attr("ows_AP");
            Amount = $(this).attr("ows_Amount");


            TotalAmount = TotalAmount + montante;


        });     
    }
      });
     alert(TotalAmount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is montante in your code was for ? where does it get its value from ? If you want to total of your amount column, below should work.

```
var TotalAmount = 0;

$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
listName: {list guid},
viewName: {view guid},
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='AP' /><FieldRef Name='Amount' /></ViewFields>",
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='AP' /><Value Type='Text'>"+areaValue+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status){
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
            var liHtml=$(this).attr("ows_Title");
            var app =$(this).attr("ows_AP");
            Amount  =0;
            Amount = parseFloat($(this).attr("ows_Amount"));
            if(!isNaN(Amount))
            {
            TotalAmount += Amount;  
            }
        });     
    }
      });
     alert(TotalAmount);
```